# Auto-formatting comments on the same line

Tags: java, comments, autoformatting

The comments goes haywire when I tried to use auto-formatting. This is the code before I use auto-formatting:

```
if (x > 125 && x < 295 && y > 180 && y < 350) { //if mouse in first tower

        if (x > bar1.x1 && x < bar1.x2 && y > bar1.y1 && y < bar1.y2){  //if mouse in first bar
        }
        if (x > bar2.x1 && x < bar2.x2 && y > bar2.y1 && y < bar2.y2){ //if mouse in second bar
        }
        if (x > bar3.x1 && x < bar3.x2 && y > bar3.y1 && y < bar3.y2){ //if mouse in third bar
        }
        if (x > bar4.x1 && x < bar4.x2 && y > bar4.y1 && y < bar4.y2){ //if mouse in fourth bar
        }
        if (x > bar5.x1 && x < bar5.x2 && y > bar5.y1 && y < bar5.y2){ //if mouse in fifth bar
        }

    }
```

This is the code after I use auto-formatting:

```
if (x > 125 && x < 295 && y > 180 && y < 350) { // if mouse in first
                                                    // tower

        if (x > bar1.x1 && x < bar1.x2 && y > bar1.y1 && y < bar1.y2) { // if
                                                                        // mouse
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // first
                                                                        // bar
        }
        if (x > bar2.x1 && x < bar2.x2 && y > bar2.y1 && y < bar2.y2) { // if
                                                                        // mouse
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // second
                                                                        // bar
        }
        if (x > bar3.x1 && x < bar3.x2 && y > bar3.y1 && y < bar3.y2) { // if
                                                                        // mouse
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // third
                                                                        // bar
        }
        if (x > bar4.x1 && x < bar4.x2 && y > bar4.y1 && y < bar4.y2) { // if
                                                                        // mouse
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // fourth
                                                                        // bar
        }
        if (x > bar5.x1 && x < bar5.x2 && y > bar5.y1 && y < bar5.y2) { // if
                                                                        // mouse
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // fifth
                                                                        // bar
        }

    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the comments on their own line?

```
if (x > bar1.x1 && x < bar1.x2 && y > bar1.y1 && y < bar1.y2) {  
    //if mouse in first bar
    doFirstBarStuff();
}
if (x > bar2.x1 && x < bar2.x2 && y > bar2.y1 && y < bar2.y2) {
    //if mouse in second bar
    doSecondBarStuff();
}
```

Comment: I did but I thought it looks before on the line that it's suppose to be commenting on.

Comment: Then put the comment on the line before the relevant `if(...)`  Maybe that will look better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the comments consider to use a method with an expressive name, e.g.:

```
boolean mouseInside(Bar bar, int x, int y) {
  return x > bar.x1 && x < bar.x2 && y > bar.y1 && y < bar.y2;
}
```

then your code can look like this and there is no need for the comments:

```
if (mosueInside(bar1, x, y))  {
}

if (mouseInside(bar2, x, y)) {        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I do it like this, it works:

```
//if-mouse-in-first-bar
```